# Why is my SUMIF with NOT(ISBLANK()) not working?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, conditional-statements, nonblank

Column A is price, column B is approval date. I would have thought:

```
=SUMIF(ColumnB,(NOT(ISBLANK(Column B))),Column A)
```

should work.  All I get is `$0.00`.

Why?
Am I using `ISBLANK` correctly or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "Am I using isblank or not wrong?". I don't fully understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know formulas like sumif do not work with logical operators you would use in an if function. Your search criteria should be a text value with operators like <, >, >=, *, ?, etc. You can check Office support for more details [SUMIF function - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

About your question and if I catch your point, if you would like to sum values in column A when column B is not empty you may try with this formula:

```
=sumif(B:B;"<>";A:A)
```

See below the result in my screen with a simple example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Perfect!  I couldn't see your screenshot (it wouldn't render at work), but the formula was just what I needed.  THANK YOU!